# Importing weather data using Google Earth Engine and visualizing them?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am a beginner in GEE.

The area of interest is already imported and visualized on the map.

Is it possible for the precipitation, to create a histogram or another diagram out of the available weather data, for the selected area and time frame?

The level of precipitation has to be compared with another time steps, therefore, I need to have a table with the amount of precipitation.

Is it possible to visualize precipitation at the map and creating a layer of precipitation?

An example of my code:

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81m");
//Import Fusion Table - for study area    
var study_area = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1QDQ2uqIShT65d4uKcq1DJpjVne_jgnBRgDzN-RaY');

//Add study_area to the map    
 Map.addLayer(study_area, {color:'green'}, 'study_area');

//To center the map at the study_area    
Map.centerObject(study_area, 6 );

//To spatially filter the weather data for the study_area    
 var spatialFiltered = imageCollection.filterBounds(study_area);   
print('spatialFiltered', spatialFiltered);

//To temporarily filter the weather data for the study_area    
var temporalFiltered = spatialFiltered.filterDate('1899-01-01', '1904-12-31');    
print('temporalFiltered', temporalFiltered);
```

Here is the link with the weather data:

https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#detail/OREGONSTATE%2FPRISM%2FAN81m

Comment: You will need to change the permissions on the fusion table to make it public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create charts in Earth Engine using the `ui.Chart` methods. You can change the chart type by using different chart methods or setting the chart type with `.setChartType`. You can turn the collection of PRISM images into a single image for visualization using the `.reduce` method. Here's code that does both using an arbitrary geometry as the study area:

```js
// Import Fusion Table - for study area    
// var study_area = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1QDQ2uqIShT65d4uKcq1DJpjVne_jgnBRgDzN-RaY');

var study_area = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-123.83038412388669, 38.476017204621904],
          [-123.03936836339949, 36.38243915984227],
          [-121.45733686974188, 36.6649580095569],
          [-122.16046197392444, 38.33827226006227]]]);

var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81m");

//Add study_area to the map    
 Map.addLayer(study_area, {color:'green'}, 'study_area');

//To center the map at the study_area    
Map.centerObject(study_area, 6 );

// Spatially filtering the images has no effect
// //To spatially filter the weather data for the study_area    
// var spatialFiltered = imageCollection.filterBounds(study_area);   
// print('spatialFiltered', spatialFiltered);

//To temporarily filter the weather data for the study_area    
var temporalFiltered = imageCollection.filterDate('1899-01-01', '1904-12-31')
  .select('ppt');    
print('temporalFiltered', temporalFiltered);


// Create a chart with time series percipitation
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series(temporalFiltered, study_area)
print(chart)

// Create an image representing mean percipitation
var meanPercipitation = temporalFiltered.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
Map.addLayer(meanPercipitation, {min:0, max: 200}, 'percipitation')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8729727fbbc991c4b5c718351ae6c2bb

It's worth noting that filtering an image collection like PRISM, where each image covers the entire spatial domain, will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you!!   I decided to use another dataset ('var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY");') for my area of investigation because it is located in Africa. 
    
I still have an issue creating an image representing the mean precipitation. A new layer is been added and created but the image is just black.    
       
Is there a way to have somehow the data from the chart into table?

Comment: @gispaew I'm also using CHIRPS in Africa. Your image is all black because you're not setting the visualization parameters. You can use the inspector to find a reasonable `max` parameter for `Map.addLayer`.